# Good way to include jar file as a library in java maven project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I got a brand new Java Maven project where I need to use an SDK, provided as a .jar file (built with ant if that helps).

I've tried several solutions:

- create a local repo using the pom.xml file
- use maven-install-plugin
- mvn install:install-file
- maven-shade-plugin (which didn't add my library to my final .jar)

each time adding a new  corresponding to my library in the pom.xml file.

However, when I package my app using maven, and launch my jar file, I get this error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException corresponding to the imports of the library.

My understanding was that there was a classpath issue, and that maven wasn't compiling my library with my source code.

I ended up using java -cp path/to/my/jar:path/to/my/lib and it worked, but is this really the right way to do it? Isn't there a way to have a ready-to-use jar file that you could run, without having to specify the library path?

Comment: `mvn install:install-file` is what I've used in the past. Make sure you did it properly and it was referenced properly in pom.xml

Comment: It appears that your `mvn install` is fine -- otherwise you'd have a build time error.

Comment: @g00se thanks for your answer, but I already tried doing this, and by checking in my .m2 folder, I can see my lib installed in my computer. Also, if I'm removing the dependency, maven is giving error, so lib is correctly installed I guess

Comment: Use a repository manager and upload it there ...

Comment: So it's the fat jar thing that's wrong